Postgres UPDATE: ошбика в текстовой константе интервала
Имеется таблица с полем "массив интервалов", пытаюсь сделать UPDATE заданного элемента:
CREATE TABLE public.intervals (
        id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
        frees      tsrange[] NULL,
);

UPDATE public.intervals
SET frees[1] = '{"[2024-07-01 06:00:00, 2024-07-01 13:00:00)"}'::tsrange
WHERE id = 4
;

Это уже из консоли, сформированный запрос. Выдает ошибку:
[22P02] ERROR: malformed range literal: 
"{"[2024-07-01 06:00:00, 2024-07-01 13:00:00)"}" 
Detail: Missing left parenthesis or bracket. Position: 42

Что тут "не так"? Уже все глаза сломал, пробовал заменять круглую скобку на квадратную и обратно.. Но мне нужен именно такой интервал [)..

А круглая скобка это что - не включать правую границу? Ну поставьте там квадратную и 12:59:59.9999 или что-то типа того. Не уверен, что можно так как вы хотите сделать, скорее всего это массив и скобки должны быть одинаковые.

Да, круглая скобка - не включать конец интервала. Надо именно так, к сожалению. Они там все такие.

решено так: UPDATE public.intervals
SET frees[$1] = tsrange($2, $3, '[)')
WHERE id = $4
;

Добавьте тогда решение в ответ.

Не могу. Пишут что "у вас отрицательная карма".. хз в каком месте она отрицательна.. ;)
